# is there a way to calculate row size between two dates in sql and oracle?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate the row size between two dates. There is a field that stores the date that the record was inserted.

Can I use that to calculate the total byte size of the rows between these two dates? If so, how? Any example or suggestions would be welcomed.

I am using SQL Server

Comment: What do you mean by size exactly, and is this for MySQL or Oracle or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: And with size do you mean actual size as in bytes or rowcount?

Comment: what is row size? bytes? number of rows? something totaly different?

Comment: yes actual size in bytes  for row counts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's write entire script together:

```
-- Determine how many rows you got between your dates

DECLARE @numbrows int;
DECLARE @byteNumber int; 

set @numbRows = (select count(*) from YOURTABLE
where DATEPARAMETER >= Convert(datetime, '2016-01-01' )
      AND DATEPARAMETER <= Convert(datetime, '2016-12-31' ));

select @numbRows as ThisManyRowsBetweenDates

-- leverage sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats to get average number of bytes for a row in your target table

set @byteNumber = (select TOP 1 avg_record_size_in_bytes FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
                  (DB_ID(N'YOURDATABASENAME'), OBJECT_ID(YOURTABLE'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED'));
select @byteNumber AS ThisManyBytesOnAveragePerRow 

-- rows * average size or rows = estimation of how many bytes you are using
select @numbRows * @byteNumber AS EstimationOfTotalBytesUsed
```

You need to edit in the following:

- YOURTABLE - table you work on
- DATEPARAMETER  - parameter that holds the dates you wanna filter on
- date literals (the '2016-01-01' and '2016-12-31') Mind the year - month - day format
- YOURDATABASENAME - your database name (without shema)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Based on the result of the query you just posted i would like to know if there is a way to get the size in bytes for the records/rows.
lets say your query returned 16  i would like to know the size in bytes for the 16.

Comment: The implementation of that would require a variable use. That will depend on DBMS you are using.

Comment: Edit in the above. I tested it on my DB with hard coded values and it works. @@version = Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64)

Comment: Thanks @DanteTheSmith. Yeah it works it  returns the estimate.  if i am doing this for oracle with sql developer do i follow similar steps?

Comment: the select with dates could be the same, but for OracleDB the average bytes per row is surely not done in same way. Unfortunately I don't have OracleDB installed on this PC to try it out. But the idea is the same, just google how to get average row bytes for a table there. Also, Oracle uses PL SQL instead T SQL so declaration and setting of variables might be different but the principle is the same.

Comment: Ok Thank you very much.  Could the above query be modified  to get the size monthly. if so would it be a easier approach to create other variables and set the the dates, and do the calculation similar to above.

Comment: MONTH ( date )  <= or >= 1,2,3,5 any integer should work for sql server, also if you need to keep year in check you can combine with date literal like:

MONTH(date) <= 6 and MONTH(date) >= 5 and date <= '2000-01-01'  and date >= '2000-12-31' would give you all the dates in 2001 that are in 5th or 6th month ?

Comment: OK. using this would allow me to see the bytes for January by itself , February by itself, march by itself  or is it a sum of all

Comment: It's how you write the expression in where clause. It can be one month in every year summed up, more monts in every year all summed up or just 1 month on 1 year or more months on 1 year

Comment: Ok great understood.

Comment: Would the column size help in making it a better calculation ?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @byteNumberJ int;
set @byteNumberJ = (select TOP 1 avg_record_size_in_bytes FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
              (DB_ID(N'Your DB'), OBJECT_ID('Your Table '), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED'));
SELECT DATENAME(mm,CREATED) MONTH, COUNT(*) * @byteNumberJ /1024 /1024 As Byte, count (*) RowCounts
FROM YourTable
where YEAR(CREATED) =2017
Group BY DATENAME(mm,CREATED)



--i tried this and it returns the month and the estimated size too as 
--well as the Row count for each month.
```