# How estimate past Database Sizing?

Tags: sql-server

i would like to estimate the size of my database for the past 5 previous months or more. Each table within the database as a created field for the date when each record was inserted. 
I have tried using the top  average record from the table and multiply it by the count based on this example i found online. ([is there a way to calculate row size between two dates in sql and oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47184888/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-row-size-between-two-dates-in-sql-and-oracle/47185173?noredirect=1#comment81362612_47185173))
When ever i do the calculations for some table the size of the table is off by 30 mb or in some case 300 mb. Could you help me in estimating the size?

```
 DECLARE @numbrows int;
 DECLARE @byteNumber int; 

 set @numbRows = (select count(*) from YOURTABLE
 where DATEPARAMETER >= Convert(datetime, '2016-01-01' )
  AND DATEPARAMETER <= Convert(datetime, '2016-12-31' ));

 select @numbRows as ThisManyRowsBetweenDates

  -- leverage sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats to get average number of bytes for a row in your target table

 set @byteNumber = (select TOP 1 avg_record_size_in_bytes FROM 
 sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
  (DB_ID(N'YOURDATABASENAME'), OBJECT_ID(YOURTABLE'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED'));
 select @byteNumber AS ThisManyBytesOnAveragePerRow 

 -- rows * average size or rows = estimation of how many bytes you are using
select @numbRows * @byteNumber AS EstimationOfTotalBytesUsed
```

I have also tried the following as well

```
   DECLARE @numbrowsJ int;
   DECLARE @byteNumberJ decimal (18,5); 
   Declare @tableName varchar(100); --
   DECLARE @Dbname varchar(100);
   Declare @year int; 

  set @Dbname = 'DataAdmin';
  SET @year = 1970;
  set @tableName = 'Customer'
  set @byteNumberJ = (select TOP 1 avg_record_size_in_bytes FROM 
  sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats
              (DB_ID(N'DataAdmin'), OBJECT_ID('dbo.Customer'), NULL, NULL , 'DETAILED'));
Insert SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing( month, SizeinMb, RowCounts, year,TableName,DatabaseName)
  --set to insert into table then from there  



  SELECT DATENAME(mm,DOB) MONTH, COUNT(*) * @byteNumberJ /1024 /1024 As 
  SizeinMB, count (*) RowCounts, DATENAME (yyyy,DOB) As 'Year', @tableName as 
 'TableName', 
  @Dbname
  FROM dbo.Customer
  where YEAR(DOB) = @year 
  Group BY DATENAME(mm,DOB),  DATENAME (yyyy,DOB)

 --insert growth 

 --use SizingCalcul



 Declare @JanTotal Decimal (18,5); 
 Declare @FebTotal Decimal (18,5); 
 Declare @MarTotal Decimal (18,5);
 Declare @aprilTotal DECIMAL (18,5);
 Declare @mayTotal Decimal (18,5);
 Declare    @JunTotal Decimal (18,5);
 Declare @JulTotal Decimal (18,5);
 Declare @AugTotal Decimal (18,5);
 Declare @SeptTotal Decimal (18,5);
 Declare @OctTotal Decimal(18,5);
 Declare @NovTotal Decimal (18,5);
 Declare @DecTotal Decimal(18,5);

 set @JanTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
 'January'and year = @year) 
 set @FebTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
'February'and year = @year)-@JanTotal;
set @MarTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
'March'and year = @year) -@FebTotal;
set @aprilTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
'April'and year = @year)-@MarTotal;
 set @mayTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
'May'and year = @year)-@aprilTotal;
set @JunTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
'June'and year = @year)-@mayTotal;
set @JulTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
'July'and year = @year)-@JunTotal;
 set @AugTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
'August'and year = @year)-@JulTotal;
set @SeptTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
'September'and year = @year)-@AugTotal;
set @OctTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
'October'and year = @year)-@SeptTotal;
set @NovTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
 'November'and year = @year)-@OctTotal;
 set @DecTotal = (Select SizeinMb from SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing where month = 
'Decimal'and year = @year)-@NovTotal;
select   @JanTotal

  update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
  set Growth =  @JanTotal
  where month  ='January' and year = @year 

  update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
  set Growth =  @FebTotal 
  where month  ='February' and year = @year  

 update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
 set Growth =  @MarTotal
 where month  ='March' and year = @year 

 update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
 set Growth =  @aprilTotal
 where month  ='April' and year = @year 

 update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
 set Growth =  @mayTotal
 where month  ='May' and year = @year 

 update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
 set Growth =  @JunTotal
 where month  ='June' and year = @year 

 update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
 set Growth =  @JulTotal
 where month  ='July' and year = @year 

 update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
 set Growth =  @AugTotal
 where month  ='August'  and year = @year 

 update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
 set Growth =  @SeptTotal
 where month  ='September' and year = @year 

 update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
 set Growth =  @OctTotal
 where month  ='October' and year = @year 

 update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
 set Growth =  @NovTotal
 where month  ='November'and year = @year 

 update SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
 set Growth =  @DecTotal
  where month  ='December' and year = @year 

  -- Average Grwthper Month 
  -- Insert this point part

SELECT SUM(Growth) As TotalYearlyGrowth, AVG(Growth) As AverageGrowthPerMonth
FROM SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
WHERE year = @year;

SELECT SUM(Growth) As TotalYearlyDbGrowth, AVG(Growth) As AverageGrowthPerYear
FROM SizingCalcul.dbo.Sizing
WHERE year = @year  and DatabaseName = @Dbname;
```

I have seen examples of how to do it going forward. By using back up as one possible measure or to insert the actually table size on a monthly basis.

Comment: What possible benefit could you derive from estimating how large your database was in the past? Since you understand how to estimate the size going forward it would be pretty much the same thing right? If the estimated growth is 2% a month it would be logical to estimate that it grew the same in the past. So instead of adding the growth amount, you simply subtract it from the current size.

Comment: Why did you tag mysql? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Thank you @Sean Lange  I understand what you are saying. I am in agreement with you.I think the person who asked for it to be done is trying to use the pas months to be able to request space for their databases. i'm guessing because it is the end of the year too as well the person wanted to be able to analyze the growth of the table on a monthly basis. I'm using sql-server

Comment: To request space for a database would require estimated future growth.

Comment: How would be the best way to get estimated future growth?

Comment: There are so many factors going on there. Do you have backups from a month ago? Or even further back? Trying to estimate possible growth is a topic far larger than a forum post.

Comment: No i don't have backups. I'm guessing that's why they wanted to do an estimate the size of the db using the created date field to calculate the size of each row and  do some calculations to get a rough estimate of the size. do you have any suggested readings that i can look into.